# how to prevent div with "overflow:hidden" to a new line when screen resized

Tags: css

When aligning my navigation bar, I met a problem when screen is resized to very small. THe css I am using is like:

```
<div id="navigation-bar">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="search-box"></div>
  <div id="user-info"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#navigation-bar {
   overflow: hidden;
}
#logo {         //on the left side of navigation bar
   float:left;  
}
#search-box {   //at the right of logo
   overflow: hidden;
}
#user-info {
   float:right;
}
```

[the example](http://jsfiddle.net/sKqZJ/476/)

It works well and align the three element in one line;

But the problem is when I resize the screen to very narrow, **search-box and user-info will break into a new line**; Is there any way I can fix that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not set your with to 33.333% to all your div so that everything centralize in one line. If you want more space on certain div just put width:50% and reduce the others. As long as total add up is 100%, it will always stays in one line.

Comment: how do you expect the three elements? in one line? or hide some?

Comment: I need the three elements at the same line and the search-box's size to be responsive with screen size; Exactly like youtube did.

Comment: @user3233063 this is what you looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/sKqZJ/481/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/sKqZJ/477/

Instead of float:left, use display:inline-block that way you can use white-space:nowrap on the parent. Negative margins were used to prevent margins that display:inline-block creates

```
#navigation-bar {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #AAA;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

#logo {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #888;
    margin-right: -4px;
}


#user-info {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  background-color: #777;
      margin-right: -4px;
}
#search-box { 
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:600px;
  width:300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #777;

}

<div id="navigation-bar">
  <div id="logo">logo</div>
  <div id="user-info">user</div>
  <div id="search-box">searchbox</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I need the search-box to be responsive with screen size, just like youtube did. inline-block cannot do that.

Comment: I read their code. the left logo is floating left and "user" is floating right. why you say they are inline-block?